# Is it possible to print something inside a Function (forEach)? Vue.Js, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working on Vuetify form generator and I want to print the generated code in the proper format.

Is it possible to print something inside a `forEach` function?

```
GiveMeCode() {
  this.Dialog = true
   this.SourceCode =
        `<template>
     <v-form ref="Form">
         <v-container class="text-center">` +
        +`</v-container>
     </v-form>
 </template>
`
}
```

Something like:(which actually returns undefined)

```
GiveMeCode() {
  this.Dialog = true
   this.SourceCode =
        `<template>
     <v-form ref="Form">
         <v-container class="text-center">` +
            this.Fields.forEach(Field => {"ITERATE & PRINT SOMETHING HERE & USE DATA PROPERTIES"})
        +`</v-container>
     </v-form>
 </template>
`
}
```

I want to use forEach loop to iterate the code. If that's not the best way what another way should I use to iterate the loop and print the output accordingly.

This is how my code syntax highliter look like. I am using Vue & Vuetfiy.
`<PrismEditor readonly :code="SourceCode" language="vue"></PrismEditor><v-card-text>`

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you mean to use `.map`? `.forEach` doesn't return anything.

Comment: ^^ and if you *did*, you probably want `.join("")` after it. Otherwise, you'll get commas between the entries in the string.

Comment: Side note: Always put the `+` at the end of the line, not the beginning of the next line.

Comment: Just let me give it a go and I'll be right back

Comment: @T.J.Crowder suggestions appreciated as I'm coming from the PHP background :)

Comment: I don't think Vue will process the HTML this way.

Comment: @connexo Yeah I'm having the came concern

Comment: Can you provide the `fileds ` array or what exactly you are trying to show because `Array.map().join("")` mentioned above will do the job

Comment: @VLAZ *Facepalm* I need to re-look into the docs. I need to remind myself basics
I'm going with array map. Still i need to replace , with new line that might be the next question. 

Thank you

Comment: why dont you create input component that takes some props or use slots and then just inside template you use v-for to map over data and display required form elements?

Answer (score 0):

I assume `GiveMeCode()` is a computed property? It seems kind of odd to put that much markup into a computed property.

You should have your markup already in your template. You can show/hide it via v-if/v-show if you need to.

Regarding your list of fields I think you have 2 options depending on what your data is (hard to tell without more context).

You can iterate over your items via [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) and spit out whatever you need. The other option would be to create a custom [filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html). Filters allow you to neatly extract your formatting code into it's own function.